# when to use the "<>" in C#

Tags: c#

When to use the "<>" in C#. I read the source code but I could not understand how it is used like.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read that first: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what? `<>`? there's no operator in C#. In Db its there.

Comment: When you are writing visual basic

Comment: I think the best thing for you would be to look for `c# tutorial` on Google or YouTube. Or if Web Development is what you want, then look for `c# asp.net tutorial` or `c# mvc tutorial`.

Comment: @Prajwal, there is for generics.

Comment: @Bauss oh that? `<T>`? didn't even think about it when I read the question. :D

Comment: There's actually a `<>` too. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<>` Is used in C# generics to declare generic types.

Ex. for a list.

`List<int>` would create a list of ints.

To explain it further you could have a type like this:

```
public class MyGenericType<T>
{
    public T MyGenericProperty { get; set; }
}
```

In which case you could do something like this:

```
var myGenericIntType = new MyGenericType<int>();
myGenericIntType.MyGenericProperty = 10;

var myGenericStringType = new MyGenericType<string>();
myGenericIntType.MyGenericProperty = "Hello World!";
```

To be even more specific, you can actually use `<>`, but it's mostly used to check if generic types are the same, generally with nullable types to check if nullable types are of a specific type.

Ex. if you want to check if `MyGenericType<string>` is actually `MyGenericType<T>` then you can do something like this:

```
if (myGenericStringType.GetType() == typeof(MyGenericType<>))
{
    // myGenericStringType is of type MyGenericType.
}
```